# Can I receive paid holiday from employer on Shabbat, even though I have not actually worked?

Tags: shabbat, tzedakah-charity, employment

Is there a contraindication to receiving holiday pay on Shabbat, where I have booked it off so as not to work Shabbat ?

Comment: Is this not what 99% of working Jews outside Israel do on Yom Tov?

Comment: Are you receiving the pay **for that day** or are you receiving **pay for vacation/personal/holiday hours accrued over prior workdays** that is "redeemed" in that pay period so as to meet a total number of "paid hours"? There is quite a difference in secular law, and that *might* make a difference Halachically.

Comment: Thank you, I will be receiving I will be receiving my normal paid salary - Pay for 1 day pay for vacation/personal/holiday hours accrued over prior workdays that is "redeemed" in that pay period so as to meet a total number of "paid hours"?  I appreciate the explanation.  I was also off sick on Yom Tov and would be entitled to receive statutory sick pay for the week, I was off - How would this be handled ?